# Create image kernel in C freeing memory error

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create a Gaussian filter kernel in C to do some image processing. I am using a 2d float array on the heap, but when I call free() on the rows I keep getting an free(): invalid pointer error. I have printed out memory locations and values of the filter to standard output and everything seems to be what I expect

```
//kernel->kernel = float **
//kernel->row_len = kernel->col_len = 5

float total_weight = 0.0;

//build the holding col
kernel->kernel = malloc(sizeof(float *) * kernel->col_len);
//get mem for each row and set the values
for (int j = 0; j < kernel->col_len; j++)
{
    kernel->kernel[j] = malloc(sizeof(float) * kernel->row_len);
    for (int i = 0; i < kernel->row_len; i++)
    {
        kernel->kernel[j][i] = ken_ComputeGuassianVal(i, j, sigma, size);
        total_weight += kernel->kernel[j][i];
    }
    //print debugging info
    printf("Create - %p\n", (kernel->kernel + j));
    for (int i = 0; i < kernel->row_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %d - %f \n", i, j, kernel->kernel[j][i]);
        printf("%p\n", (*(kernel->kernel + j) + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Normalise the kernel otherwise brightness will be added to the image
for (int j = 0; j < kernel->col_len; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < kernel->row_len; i++)
    {
        kernel->kernel[j][i] /= total_weight;
    }
}
for (int j = 0; j < kernel->col_len; j++)
{
    printf("Attempting to free memory at location %p\n", (kernel->kernel + j));
    free(kernel->kernel + j);
    printf("\n");
}
free(kernel->kernel);
```

Here is the output I am getting to standard output

```
Create - 0x55aa2a80d4e0
0, 0 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a7ed8d0
1, 0 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a7ed8d4
2, 0 - 0.000001
0x55aa2a7ed8d8
3, 0 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a7ed8dc
4, 0 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a7ed8e0

Create - 0x55aa2a80d4e8
0, 1 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a84c6a0
1, 1 - 0.001083
0x55aa2a84c6a4
2, 1 - 0.034551
0x55aa2a84c6a8
3, 1 - 0.001083
0x55aa2a84c6ac
4, 1 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a84c6b0

Create - 0x55aa2a80d4f0
0, 2 - 0.000001
0x55aa2a7f96a0
1, 2 - 0.034551
0x55aa2a7f96a4
2, 2 - 1.102181
0x55aa2a7f96a8
3, 2 - 0.034551
0x55aa2a7f96ac
4, 2 - 0.000001
0x55aa2a7f96b0

Create - 0x55aa2a80d4f8
0, 3 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a80d510
1, 3 - 0.001083
0x55aa2a80d514
2, 3 - 0.034551
0x55aa2a80d518
3, 3 - 0.001083
0x55aa2a80d51c
4, 3 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a80d520

Create - 0x55aa2a80d500
0, 4 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a7eddf0
1, 4 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a7eddf4
2, 4 - 0.000001
0x55aa2a7eddf8
3, 4 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a7eddfc
4, 4 - 0.000000
0x55aa2a7ede00

Destroy - 0x55aa2a7ed8d0
Attempting to free memory at location 0x55aa2a80d4e0

Destroy - 0x55aa2a84c6a0
Attempting to free memory at location 0x55aa2a80d4e8
free(): invalid pointer
[1]    13936 abort      ./dipcw
```

I have tried both array notation kernel->kernel[j] and (kernel->kernel + j). I am using elementary linux 5.0 and gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)

Edit: Changed the stop condition variable in the normalization loop to use the same variables as the other loops. Added free statement for the double pointer at the end

Comment: Your loops for "Normalise the kernel" doesn't use the same sizes as the other loops. Is `size` equal to either `kernel->col_len` or `kernel->row_len`?

Comment: size is equal to both of them, sorry that is because I have trimmed away some of the function that was not relevant to my problem

Comment: `free(kernel->kernel + j);` -->> you probably want `free(kernel->kernel[ j] );` (though you need to the *master* pointer-array too)

Comment: @joop when I change free to that then I get an invalid pointer on the first loop condition where j = 0

Comment: They are in the example code that I have created, my actual code originally had the free in a separate function but when that didn't work I moved it over to the malloc function to debug it

Answer (score 0):

The rule is: there should be a corresponding `free()` for every `malloc()`

---

```
struct matrix {
        unsigned nrow;
        unsigned ncol;
        float ** ptrs;
        } data;

/* allocate */

unsigned row, col;

data.ptrs = malloc (data.nrow * sizeof *data.ptrs);                 // <<< [A]
for (row=0; row < data.nrow; row++) {                               // <<< [B]
        data.ptrs[row] = malloc (data.ncol * sizeof *data.ptrs[0]); // <<< [C]
        }


/* there should be a corresponding free for every malloc
   , but in the "inside-out" order :
 */

unsigned row, col;

for (row=0; row < data.nrow; row++) {     // <<< [B]
        free( data.ptrs[row] );           // <<< [C]
        }

free(data.ptrs);                          // <<< [A]
```

---

Note: for simplicity, I swapped rows/columns , and I used `matrix.field` instead of `pointer->field`.

Comment: I think I do don't I? I allocate the array of float pointers `kernel->kernel = malloc(sizeof(float *) * kernel->col_len);` and free them `free(kernel->kernel);` I also have two sets of loops of the same iteration count to malloc or free the array of floats

Comment: Yes, but your pointer arithmetic in the free() call is incorrect. The argument to free() should be equivalent to the lval you got from:  `lval = malloc(...)`. (you omit one level of indirection)

Comment: Ok, I understand that from a theoretical point of view thank you. But in this case, what should the code be for my free?

Comment: `free(kernel->kernel[j]);` As I said in my comment. This matches to your `kernel->kernel[j] = malloc(...)` at the top of your first loop.

Comment: As I replied to your previous comment when I change to `free(kernel->kernel[j]);` it doesn't work either. And in my original question said I tried both syntaxes. I get the end of my output `Destroy - 0x55a7d545f8d0
Attempting to free memory at location 0x55a7d547f4e0
free(): invalid pointer
[1]    15530 abort      ./dipcw`